# Dataframe utilizando R

Tags: r, microsoft-excel, layout, dataframe

Estou com vários arquivos .xls e todos tem o mesmo layout.

Quero deixá-los em um dataframe único, por exemplo:

```
    df1
    nome idade sexo
    Fulano 22 M

    df2
    nome idade sexo
    Fulana 27 F

    dfJuncao
    nome idade sexo
    Fulana 27 F
    Fulano 22 M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
juncao <- data.frame(data.table::rbindlist(df1,df2 , fill = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `rbind`.

```
x <- data.frame("Nome" = "Fulano", "Idade" = 22, "Sexo" = "M")
y <- data.frame("Nome" = "Fulana", "Idade" = 27, "Sexo" = "F")
z <- rbind(x, y)
```

A saída deve ser algo como:

```
    Nome Idade Sexo
1 Fulano    22    M
2 Fulana    27    F
```

Comment: Eu tive um retorno diferente, 
z
              [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]   
planilhas List,14 List,14 List,14 List,14 List,14